# Create Selenoid Image With DockerFile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, continuous-integration, selenoid

I need to publish a Dockerfile that contains https://aerokube.com/selenoid.

This has to be a Dockerfile so I can publish it to our container registry which will be used as a service container as part of the pipeline/text execution https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/service-containers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Here is my dockerfile

```
FROM alpine:3.14

# Update Package
RUN apk update

# Install Selenoid Configuration Manager
RUN wget -O /usr/bin/cm https://github.com/aerokube/cm/releases/download/1.8.5/cm_linux_amd64 \
    && chmod +x /usr/bin/cm

# create dir
RUN mkdir -p /etc/selenoid

# Copy browsers.json
COPY  browsers.json /etc/selenoid/browsers.json

EXPOSE 4444

CMD["/usr/bin/cm", "-conf", "/etc/selenoid/browsers.json"]
```

My browsers.json file is located in the same directory as the Dockerfile.

In my local testing I get the following error when trying to run the container

```
Error: unknown command "/etc/selenoid/browsers.json" for "cm"
Run 'cm --help' for usage.
```

I have also tried updating the command to be

```
CMD ["/usr/bin/cm", "selenoid","start", "-conf", "/etc/selenoid/browsers.json"]
```

But the error is even more insane

```
Failed to initialize: [can not access Docker: make sure you have Docker installed and current user has access permissions]
```

Changing CMD to ENTRYPOINT is the same result

Answer (score 1):

You are doing weird things. CM tool was never expected to be published in a container. This is just like a `setup.exe` for quick Selenoid installation. How to build a Docker images is described in this documentation section: https://aerokube.com/selenoid/latest/#_contributing_development Simply copy `browsers.json` as `/etc/selenoid/browsers.json` after doing steps from the docs and provide this path to `/usr/bin/selenoid` command using `-conf` flag. Original Dockerfile is published here: https://github.com/aerokube/selenoid/blob/master/Dockerfile

Comment: While strange, this is the only way to get it to work with another docker container through an azure devops pipeline otherwise the docker network is a bit of a mess
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/service-containers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's a typo but in your question you have a space missing in the original Dockerfile.

```
CMD["/usr/bin/cm", "-conf", "/etc/selenoid/browsers.json"]
```

Should be:

```
CMD ["/usr/bin/cm", "-conf", "/etc/selenoid/browsers.json"]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The error `unknown command "/etc/selenoid/browsers.json" for "cm"` suggests there is an issue with the command syntax in the Dockerfile. The command parameters are not being recognized correctly.
Make sure the [CMD instruction](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) is properly formatted as a JSON array.

```
CMD ["/usr/bin/cm", "selenoid", "start", "-conf", "/etc/selenoid/browsers.json"]
```

And the error message `can not access Docker: make sure you have Docker installed and current user has access permissions` indicates that the Selenoid service is unable to access Docker.
Try and mount the Docker socket inside your container. That can be done by adding a [volume mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) when running the Docker container.

```bash
docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock your-image-name
```

Finally, using [`ENTRYPOINT`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) instead of `CMD` is advisable when you want your container to run as an executable.

Your revised Dockerfile would be:

```
FROM alpine:3.14

RUN apk update && \
    wget -O /usr/bin/cm https://github.com/aerokube/cm/releases/download/1.8.5/cm_linux_amd64 && \
    chmod +x /usr/bin/cm && \
    mkdir -p /etc/selenoid

COPY browsers.json /etc/selenoid/browsers.json

EXPOSE 4444

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/cm"]
CMD ["selenoid", "start", "-conf", "/etc/selenoid/browsers.json"]
```